# Finding the magnitude of a function

Tags: solution-verification

> Find $|X(\omega)|$ where $$
> X(\omega)=\frac{1}{1-ae^{i\omega}}
> $$

Multiplication of the conjugate of the denominator on its numerator and denominator yields
$$
X(\omega)=\frac{1-a\cos(\omega)-i\sin(\omega)}{1-2a\cos(\omega)+\omega^2}
$$
which should give
$$
|X(\omega)|=\sqrt{\frac{1-2a\cos(\omega)+a^2}{1-2a\cos(\omega)+\omega^2}}
$$
However, the final answer on the book is
$$
|X(\omega)|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-2a\cos(\omega)+\omega^2}}
$$
Is the answer on the book wrong?

Comment: Did you type $\omega^{2}$ for $a^{2}$ by mistake?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy yes, my solution in the paper had that from the start. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X(\omega)=\frac {1-a\cos (\omega)+ia\sin (\omega)} {1-2a\cos (\omega)+a^{2}}$$ and $$|X(\omega)|=\frac {\sqrt {(1-a\cos (\omega))^{2}+a^{2}\sin^{2} (\omega)}} {1-2a\cos (\omega)+a^{2}}$$ $$=\frac {\sqrt {1+a^{2}-2a\cos (\omega)}}{1-2a\cos (\omega)+a^{2}}$$ $$=\frac 1  {\sqrt {1+a^{2}-2a\cos (\omega)}}$$